# How to fix broken dependencies when installing old/archived packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, packages, apt-get

I am trying to install opencv version 2.1. My codebase requires opencv 2.1, so upgrading is not an option. Specifically, I am trying to install the packages: **libhighgui2.1 libcvaux2.1 libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libhighgui-dev**.

My solution thus far has been to change /etc/apt/sources.list to pull from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty. However, when I `apt-get install libhighgui-dev`, I recieve the error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
 libhighgui-dev : Depends: libjpeg-dev 
                  Depends: libtiff4-dev but it is not going to be installed 
                  Depends: libjasper-dev but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

On `apt-get install libjpeg-dev':

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg62-dev : Depends: libjpeg62 (= 6b1-1ubuntu1) but 6b1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix these broken dependencies?

Comment: Not a programming question

Comment: @AdrianCornish Oh whoops, where do I put this then?

Comment: No worries the community will vote to move it to a better forum automagically for you :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pixelbook installing r-base dependency error](https://superuser.com/questions/1422059/pixelbook-installing-r-base-dependency-error)